# Select columns in list and replace it with names

Tags: r, list

```
number<-list(matrix(1:6,2,3),matrix(2:7,2,3))
fruit<-c("apple","banana","pear","orange","berry","grape","watermelon")
```

**Aim**: Select the first two columns of the list "number", and then replace related number with the name in "fruit".

My code is as follows.

```
result<-lapply(number,function(a) {fruit[a[,c(1,2)]]})
```

But the result is not what I want.

```
[[1]]
[1] "apple"  "banana" "pear"   "orange"

[[2]]
[1] "banana" "pear"   "orange" "berry"
```

while my expected result is as follows;

```
[[1]]
[1] "apple"     "pear" 
[2] "banana"  "orange"

[[2]]
[1] "banana"  "orange" 
[2]   "pear"   "berry"
```

Could you help me with this, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(number, function(x) {
    x[, -3] <- fruit[x[, -3]]; 
    x[, -3]
})`?

Comment: Or the more fun `lapply(number, function(x) \`dim<-\`(fruit[x[, -3]], dim(x[, -3])))`

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you the right answer, but it vectorizes your matrix.  Try:

```
result <- lapply(number,function(a) {matrix(fruit[a[,c(1,2)]],nrow=nrow(a))})
```

Comment: "nrow" really helpful! Thank you so much!